# Query script format giving unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, informix

I perform a certain query often and wanted to write a simple bash script to run. When I set it to run as the following

```
#!/bin/bash

dbaccess davedb <<! 2>/dev/null
set isolation dirty read;
SELECT cpe_localization_code
FROM hct_profile
WHERE hct_mac_address = '$mac';
```

it works however I have to hard set the $mac variable and am trying to set it to read from a file.

If I structure it like this is it reads from the file but does as it states and echo's each time so I get a mess on screen.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="/t"
file=list.csv

while read mac; do

echo "SET isolation dirty read;
SELECT cpe_localization_code
FROM hct_profile
WHERE hct_mac_address = '$mac'
;" | dbaccess davedb

done <"$file"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Returns

```
Database selected.


Isolation level set.



cpe_localization_+

82345

1 row(s) retrieved.



Database closed.


Database selected.


Isolation level set.



cpe_localization_+

82345-1

1 row(s) retrieved.



Database closed.
```

I tried this but gives me an unexpected end of file.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="/t"
file=list.csv

while read mac; do

dbaccess davedb <<! 2>/dev/null
set isolation dirty read;
SELECT cpe_localization_code
FROM hct_profile
WHERE hct_mac_address = '$mac';

done <"$file"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Help pointing to me in the right direction to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `dbaccess` command but if it is an interactive command you can use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS="/t"
file=list.csv

while read mac; do

dbaccess davedb <<EndOfQuery 2>/dev/null
set isolation dirty read;
SELECT cpe_localization_code
FROM hct_profile
WHERE hct_mac_address = '$mac';
EndOfQuery

done <"$file"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Your script was almost there. You just had to terminate the [here-doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) before the end of file.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! And thank you for the link to the ref page.

Comment: It would have been possible to keep the original `!` by putting the matching `!` on a line on its own at the end.  I often use `EOF` as the marker for the end of here-doc (and sometimes  `!` or EOS or EOT), but each to their own.

Comment: Yes. I changed it to make it explicit. Also, SQL queries sometime use != for not equals, and it would cause problem then.